# How can I replace a content of a div from an external html?

Tags: jquery, html

I want catch a content of a div. That div there is in a foreign html.
I tried

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
               $('#mainbox').load('includes/divone.html');
           });
```

div mainbox is a maincontent

The html page divone.html is :

```html
<body>
<div id="div1">hey bulldog!</div>


</body>
```

But it doesn't run!

Comment: Could it be that your `div` has an `id` of `div1` instead of `mainbox`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you waiting for the page to be loaded?
Remember that load is a non-blocking api.

Here is the code that works for me

Main Page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainbox"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#mainbox" ).load( "/load.html", function () {
             $('#div1').html("hello world");
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Loaded Page:

```
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
```